# Inflating FXML from subdirectory

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a Launcher class which I want to use to open a new window.

From main in Launcher, I'm calling :

`ChatList chatList = new ChatList(communicator);`

The constructor of ChatList calls method `showChatList()` where I try to inflate a FXML document:

```
    private void showChatList() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/ChatList.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However I'm getting a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.` where I'm calling `fxmlLoader.load()`. My project file structure is as follows:

[image: project structure]

I've tried putting in an absolute file path to the FXML file but still had no luck.

Can anyone help me understand what the general principle is behind inflating FXMLs in JavaFX (with multiple stages) or point me to a good resource that they've come across.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps whatsoever, but I have to do `new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(//path);` Worth a try.

Comment: So you're saying I do this: `FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("//fxml/ChatList.fxml"));` ? It still doesn't work I should note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but maybe can help someone .

You have to write all the path of the fxml. 
In your case is:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/client/fxml/ChatList.fxml"));
```

Another example:
Youproject/Src/parentpackage/childpackage/fxmlToGet.fxml

If you want to get the fxml in childpackage you have to write:

```
FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/parentpackage/childpackage/fxmlToGet.fxml"));
```